# postgreSQL slow query with high shared read

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, explain, postgresql-performance

i have a problem with my postgreSQL database, actually i'm developer not DBA so i don't have enough experience to deal with problems like this.
I ran this query at my psql:

```
explain (analyze true, buffers true) select json_build_object('tracker_id', tracker_id,   
'page_name', page_name, 'post_id',item_id, 'item', item, 'created_time', created_time ,   
'updated_time', updated_time, 'full_picture', full_picture, 'url', url, 'message', message,   
'comments_number', comments_number, 'reactions_count', reactions_count, 'reaction_counts',   
reaction_counts, 'shares_number', shares_number, 'sentiment_label', sentiment_label, 'dialect',   
dialect, 'domain', domain, 'user', from_user, 'attachment', attachment, 'status', status ) FROM   
fb_public_pages_feeds where tracker_id = 10033  AND created_time >= '2021-08-01 21:00:00' AND   
created_time <= '2021-08-10 06:11:25' order by created_time DESC;
```

and here is the result of it:

```
 Sort  (cost=131413.32..131573.66 rows=64136 width=40) (actual time=228599.459..228772.292 rows=114026 loops=1)
   Sort Key: created_time DESC
   Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 90848kB
   Buffers: shared hit=23328 read=182279 dirtied=16582 written=3945, temp read=11356 written=11356
   ->  Index Scan using fb_public_pages_feeds_tracker_id_idx on fb_public_pages_feeds  (cost=0.56..126292.43 rows=64136 width=40) (actual time=35794.622..146061.562 rows=114026 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (tracker_id = 10033)
         Filter: ((created_time >= '2021-08-01 21:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_time <= '2021-08-10 06:11:25'::timestamp without time zone))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 32090
         Buffers: shared hit=23328 read=182279 dirtied=16582 written=3945
 Planning time: 1.046 ms
 Execution time: 228814.096 ms
```

as i read, this means that most of data are read from disk which is bad behavior and i need to read it from cache, but despite i ran this query multiple times it never get cached like there is something make my cache always busy.

my system has a heavy work load, hundereds of insertion & updates per minute.
so how can i solve a problem like that? increasing shared buffers or running VACUUM & ANALYZE manually?
**here are my config:**

shared_buffers: 10GB
shared_preload_libraries: ''
work_mem: 10485kB
effective_cache_size: 30GB
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor     | 0.1
autovacuum_analyze_threshold        | 50
autovacuum_freeze_max_age           | 200000000
autovacuum_max_workers              | 3
autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age | 400000000
autovacuum_naptime                  | 1min
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay        | 20ms
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit        | -1
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor      | 0.2
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold         | 50

**and here more information about the table that face this problem from pg_stat_all_tables:**
relname             | fb_public_pages_feeds
seq_scan            | 37418
seq_tup_read        | 31025964155
idx_scan            | 10042277
idx_tup_fetch       | 963803744
n_tup_ins           | 3035565
n_tup_upd           | 9180652
n_tup_del           | 0
n_tup_hot_upd       | 2174258
n_live_tup          | 6253232
n_dead_tup          | 6637730
n_mod_since_analyze | 10332947
last_vacuum         |
last_autovacuum     | 2021-05-28 02:20:45.812805+00
last_analyze        |
last_autoanalyze    | 2021-03-23 18:29:05.939813+00
vacuum_count        | 0
autovacuum_count    | 16
analyze_count       | 0
autoanalyze_count   | 4

my postgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 10.5
system RAM: 64GB
system CPU: 16 CPU

**UPDATE:**
here is the result of VACUUM command which i ran manually:
[image]

Comment: Here's the culprit, at least 1st pass: `work_mem: 10485kB`  leading to disk sort ~9 * its size. `Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 90848kB`. Increase your work_men.